# Possible to use Google Maps API v3 without API Key?

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps-api-3, flex3, api-key

I've got a Flex application that uses the Google Maps component. Is it possible to configure the component to use Google Maps API v3 without API Key?  If not, is there a workaround to use the JavaScript API?  Or a timeline for providing swc using Google Maps API v3?

I currently perform client-side geocoding using the Google Maps API v3 webservice, but I need to also display maps and allow user to interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, realize that the Javascript API and the Flash API are different API's.

I imagine that they will porting the no API key feature to the Flash API soon.

However, I have no used the Flash API in a while and Google may be moving away from maintaining it. It doubt that they will though. They have a lot invested in the Flash API.